# Handle variable as file with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a pandas dataframe out of a list variable.
With `pd.DataFrame()` I am not able to declare delimiter which leads to just one column per list entry.

If I use `pd.read_csv()` instead, I of course receive the following error

> ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>

If there a way to use `pd.read_csv()` with my list and not first save the list to a csv and read the csv file in a second step?

I also tried `pd.read_table()` which also need a file or buffer object.

Example data (seperated by tab stops):

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
12      Info1   34.1
15      Info4   674.1
```

> test = ["Col1\tCol2\tCol3", "12\tInfo1\t34.1","15\tInfo4\t674.1"]

Current workaround:

```
with open(f'{filepath}tmp.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    [f.write(line + "\n") for line in consolidated_file]
        

df = pd.read_csv(f'{filepath}tmp.csv', sep='\t', index_col=1 )
```

Comment: you could convert it to nested list `[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'], ['12', 'Info1', '34.1'], ['15', 'Info4', '674.1']]` and then use `DataFrame` - like in answer. OR if you would convert it to single string (using `'\n')` as line separator then you could use `read_csv` with `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO` to create file in memory. `io.BytesIO` is popular if you get file (data, image, audio) from network and you want to use it without saving on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems simpler to convert it to nested list like in other answer

```py
import pandas as pd

test = ["Col1\tCol2\tCol3", "12\tInfo1\t34.1","15\tInfo4\t674.1"]

data = [line.split('\t') for line in test]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```

but you can also convert it back to single string (or get it directly form file on socket/network as single string) and then you can use `io.BytesIO` or `io.StringIO` to simulate file in memory.

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

test = ["Col1\tCol2\tCol3", "12\tInfo1\t34.1","15\tInfo4\t674.1"]

single_string = "\n".join(test)

file_like_object = io.StringIO(single_string)

df = pd.read_csv(file_like_object, sep='\t')
```

or shorter

```py
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("\n".join(test)), sep='\t')
```

This method is popular when you get data from network (socket, web API) as single string or data.

Comment: Thank you, the first solution works fine. Unfortunately, the variant with io leads to the fact that I get only one column in my dataframe in which col1, col2 and col3 are contained.

Comment: I forgot `sep='\t'` like with normal file.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split('\t') for x in test])
print(df)
```

and you want header as your first row then

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

Comment: you could also first convert to nested list `data = [line.split('\t') for line in test]` and later use it in `df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])`